# Renaming application

Tags: android, eclipse

i have created a sample projet in android named 'myProject'. But while i installing to this my phone name in the phone like'com.project.myProject'. Any idea how to rename this ?

Comment: you can change your app name from Strings.xml file....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml.

The attribute to set your application name is `android:label`.

You can use it in 2 nodes:

- First is in `<application>`. It defines the name of your application in the "application" section of the settings in Android.
- Second is in `<activity>`. Define the name where you have the LAUNCHER category to set application title in drawer.

Please note that Eclipse use `@string/app_name` by default for those values.

Answer (score 0):

Go this strings.xml file you found you application name then you can able to change it.

Android `Project > res -> values -> strings.xml ->  <string name="app_name">`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have build.xml file in your root folder, then change the attribute of `project` node like this :

```
<project name="YOUR_APP_NAME" default="help">
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Values folder of your project, you will find a strings.xml file, give any name of your application to "app_name" attribute and set the same attribute to manifest.xml file within application tab. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Going to res folder of app and In the strings.xml file of Value folder , there is an element app_name that is used in the Android menifest file in level field as the application name.
You would be change the name of app_name as you  want to display the application name and saved then run application.